Fubini property of Sobolev space on domains
Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^n$ be a bounded Lipschitz domain. The standard Sobolev space $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$ is the space of all $f\in L^p(\Omega)$ such that $\|f\|_{W^{k,p}}^p=\sum_{|\alpha|\le k}\int_\Omega|\partial^\alpha f|^p<\infty$.
My question is, when $1<p<\infty$, do we have the equivalent norm
$$\|f\|_{W^{k,p}(\Omega)}^p\approx\int_\Omega|f|^p+\sum_{j=1}^n\int_\Omega\Big|\frac{\partial^k f}{\partial x_j^k}\Big|^p?$$
Note that when $\Omega=\mathbb R^n$ the result is true since $\sum_{j=1}^n\partial_j^k$ is an order $k$ elliptic operator when $k$ is even and $L^p(\mathbb R^n)$ is closed under singular integrals. For a reference, see Triebel's Theory of Function Spaces I, Chapter 2.5.13, which contains a more general version of the result.

"when $\Omega=\mathbb R^n$ the result is true" -- Can you provide a reference to this?

@IosifPinelis I don't have a good one in head, so I just quote Triebel's book.

One usually proves the norm equivalence as you state using Ehrling's lemma for which you need Rellich-Kondrachov. On a Lipschitz domain, you certainly have Rellich-Konrdachov.

@Hannes I don’t believe in the “usual method”. They just push the derivatives to highest order but do not exclude the usage of mixed derivatives. For Besov and Triebel-Lizorkin spaces you have to use the structure of the extension operator. I just hope there is a simpler proof for Sobolev spaces.

I thinks this is not true in general unless the domain has smooth boundary or is some dilation of an hypercube. Because as you mentioned at the end of your post this would imply that the Laplacian (or higher poly Laplacian) have their domain to coincide with a standard Sobolev space. Which is wrong for C¹ domains for instance.

@ToGle Do you have a reference for the negative result?
